# When running the program nothing happens and it goes back to the command prompt

Tags: python

Basically, when i run the program nothing happens in the command prompt and it skips it and goes back to where the prompt was before I ran the program.  I called Prime() at the bottom of the code and made sure that I have called all other codes within each code.  It doesn't give me any errors when I run it.  It just basically skips the program when run.

```
def Prime():
    X = 3
    N = 2
    Prime1()

def Prime1():
    global X
    global N
    global Y
    global A

    A = (X / N)

    A = round(A,1) + 1

    Y = (X%N)

    if(N < A or N == A):
        Prime2()

    else:
        print(X)
        X = X + 2
        Prime1()



def Prime2():
    global X
    global R
    global N
    global Y
    global A
    Y = (X%N)
    N = N + 1
    if(Y == 0):
        X = X + 2

        Prime1()




Prime()
```

Comment: I recommend you add additional `print()` statements in your program at various points to see which parts of the program are actually executing.

Comment: How would you know whether or not it worked? No function returns anything. And why is everything `global`?! Consider reading [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Comment: Why are `X` and `N` assigned _before_ you call `Prime1()`? I'm getting a `NameError`.

Comment: It almost looks like you're trying to write Fortran in Python. So much global... so many single-letter-variables.

Answer (score 2):

With your values `X = 3` and `N = 2` your condition

```
if (N < A or N == A)
```

is `true` so the `else` part with your `print(X)` statement is not executed and in `Prime2` `Y` has the value `1` so your programm is done and exits without any printed output.

And I would suggest you to have a look at the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/) how to write code in python, and create a better structure for your application without that amount of `global` variables. Try to pass the values as arguments and return a result etc.